# Let $A$ be a real $n × n$ matrix whose columns are orthogonal with respect to the standard scalar product on $R^n$. Find $A^{−1}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I don't really understand what it means by having columns that are orthogonal with respect to the standard scalar product. Does that mean:

If $v_1$ and $v_2$ are some of the columns of $A$, then $v_1 . v_2 = 0$ ?

If not, what does it mean? If so, how does that help me in finding $A^{-1}$ ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You have $(A e_i)^TA e_j  = \delta_{ij} \lambda_k$, or in other words $e_i^T A^TA e_j  = \delta_{ij} \lambda_k$, from which it follows that $A^T A = \Lambda$, where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix with entries $\lambda_k$. Assuming that $\lambda_k \neq 0 $ for all $k$, this gives $(\Lambda^{-1}A^T) A = I $, from which it follows that $\Lambda^{-1}A^T = A^{-1}$.

Comment: "Assuming that $\lambda_k \neq 0 $ for all $k$" - does this not follow from orthogonality? If a $\lambda_k $ was 0 then the columns would not be orthogonal

Comment: @user61369: I have converted your answer to a comment. Answers should be reserved for posts that answer the question. But because you do not have 50 reputation points yet, [you can only comment on your own questions and answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work/19757#19757). So, you didn't do anything wrong; the "add comment" button will only appear for you once you gain 50 points. Here is an [explanation of reputation points](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work/7238#7238).

Comment: @user61369: If a $\lambda_k=0$, then the corresponding column is $0$, which is trivially orthogonal to everything.